# Фильтрация в ListView

Tags: getview, android, listview, java

Пытаюсь сделать поиск в ListView. Мой адаптер:

```
public class MyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter{

public static ArrayList<Item> data = new ArrayList<Item>();
Context context;
public MyAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId, ArrayList<Item> arr) {
super(context, textViewResourceId, arr);
if (arr != null) {
data = arr;
}
this.context = context;   
// TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
return data.size();
}
@Override
public Object getItem(int num) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
return data.get(num);
}
@Override
public long getItemId(int arg0) {
return arg0;
}
@Override
public View getView(int i, View someView, ViewGroup arg2) {
LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);

if (someView == null) {
someView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.rect, arg2, false);
}

final TextView header1 = (TextView) someView.findViewById(R.id.Text);
header1.setText(data.get(i).text1);
return someView;
}
}
```

Активити:

```
pullToRefreshView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvMain);
final MyAdapter lol = new MyAdapter(this,R.id.lvMain ,data);
pullToRefreshView.setAdapter(lol);

data.add(new Item("privet"));
data.add(new Item("kak dela"));
data.add(new Item("dela narm"));
data.add(new Item("ohuet"));
data.add(new Item("nastya"));
data.add(new Item("prove"));
EditText txt = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.OMG);
txt.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
@Override
public void onTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
lol.getFilter().filter(arg0);
lol.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
@Override
public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2,
int arg3) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
}
@Override
public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
}
});
```

Но при изменении EditText'a ничего не происходит. Что я делаю не так?

Answer (score 1):

Надо писать свою реализацию фильтра или переопределить метод `compare()` в `Item` классе.